# Ruby/Rails Collection to Collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a two tables joined with a join table - this is just pseudo code:

```
Library
Book
LibraryBooks
```

What I need to do is if i have the id of a library, i want to get all the libraries that all the books that this library has are in.

So if i have Library 1, and Library 1 has books A and B in them, and books A and B are in Libraries 1, 2, and 3, is there an elegant (one line) way todo this in rails?

I was thinking:

```
l = Library.find(1)
allLibraries = l.books.libraries
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Suggestions?

Comment: So you want all the libraries that have books ? The above code snippet wouldn't it just return the same library as l. Its like asking all your books, who their owner is.Its you. A lil bit of confusion.. but Jim's ans below will do the collation trick.

Comment: All the libraries that have books that are also in this library, yes?

Comment: @Jim - that's exactly what i want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
l = Library.find(:all, :include => :books)
l.books.map { |b| b.library_ids }.flatten.uniq
```

Note that `map(&:library_ids)` is slower than `map { |b| b.library_ids }` in Ruby 1.8.6, and faster in 1.9.0.

I should also mention that if you used `:joins` instead of `include` there, it would find the library and related books all in the same query speeding up the database time. `:joins` will only work however if a library has books.

Comment: the slowness of Symbol#to_proc is usually outweighed by the database calls.

Comment: I do not see how this could work.  The first line will return an array of Library objects (well actually a proxy, but with the same methods).  This array will not have a "books" method, so line two will fail, won't it?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps:

```
l.books.map {|b| b.libraries}
```

or

```
l.books.map {|b| b.libraries}.flatten.uniq
```

if you want it all in a flat array.

Of course, you should really define this as a method on Library, so as to uphold the noble cause of encapsulation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a one-dimensional array of libraries returned, with duplicates removed.

```
l.books.map{|b| b.libraries}.flatten.uniq
```

Answer (score 2):

One problem with

```
l.books.map{|b| b.libraries}.flatten.uniq
```

is that it will generate one SQL call for each book in l. A better approach (assuming I understand your schema) might be:

```
LibraryBook.find(:all, :conditions => ['book_id IN (?)', l.book_ids]).map(&:library_id).uniq
```

Comment: This isn't strictly true, depending on what has been loaded initially.

Comment: sorry, I should have made that clear: I'm assuming you haven't preloaded anything other than l (the initial library)

Comment: oops... not sure this works ... did you mean LibraryBook or Library?